# how do I count every hour with epoch and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make a count row created between each hour within 24 hours?

I have a table like this

```
[ID] [Time(epoch time)]
```

Thank you

Comment: can you expand the question? I am a little unsure of what you need.

Comment: you want track every 24 hour created rows or last 24 hours created records ?

Comment: Just check the answer, basically i need to get the count of records of each hour in the past day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have understood you question

```
select from_unixtime(visittime,'%H') as h,count(*) as total
from table
where from_unixtime(visittime) >= now() - interval 1 day
group by h
```

Comment: yep, this is it, how ever i did an edit: select from_unixtime(`VisitTime`,'%H %m/%d/%y') as h,count(*) as total 
from Logs 
WHERE `VisitTime` > 1303134630 
group by h